# How to add a new column on a TABLE 1 with a value from a TABLE 2?

Tags: mysql, distinct

I want to create a table called `data-insights` which has one row and a few columns with some basic information on my database such as MAX,MIN,AVG(sales).

In the code to create the table I want to add a calculated number (the number of customers) from another table  `TABLE2`

```
CREATE `data-insights`

AS(
SELECT SUM(sales),
   MAX(sales),
   MIN(sales),
   ROUND(AVG(sales),0)
   FROM `TABLE1`
    );

ALTER TABLE `data-insights`
ADD COLUMN nb_customers VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT '(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customers) FROM `TABLE2`)';
```

The last part which starts with ALTER, does add a column but with a STATIC info instead of a the calculated number of customers.